# Context Free Grammar tips

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

So I've come across this problem in my study of context free grammars and I have no idea how to get the production rules of this English sentence.

Language L is defined as:
"All odd-length strings over {a, b}∗ with
middle symbol a."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the string from the middle and always add one letter to both sides

```
A -> aAa | aAb | bAa | bAb | a
```

Comment: and what would L(G) be in this scenario? where G is the context free grammar

Comment: {0...a...n | a= n\2, n mod 2 != 0} is what I have but I'm not sure about it

Comment: L(G) = { a^R |  ∈ {a,b}* }

Comment: @Harald That's all odd-length *palindromes* with middle symbol *a*. He just wants odd length strings, so L(G) = { xay | |x| = |y|, x, y in {a, b}* }

Comment: @Patrick87 The comment of Harald is incorrect but the grammar he provided is correct. It does not produce palindromes. If the productions were limited to aAa | bAb, that would have been palindromes, but here, we also have aAb | bAa which generate random strings

Comment: @Hazem The comment refers to his comment which uses set notation to define the language of odd-length palindromes with middle symbol a. The grammar in the body of the answer is correct.